# angular 8 loads application assets twice

Tags: angular, bundle, assets

i have a ng 8 application available on (https://anyteam.work/en/) if you kindly inspect the network tab, angular making request twice!!! the files are 4mb but since they have been called twice, my page load is almost 9mb!!! and one more thing, when my application was in angular 7, my bundle size was 3mb, after changing to angular 8, bundle size of same code became 3.5mb, i was wondering this 500k extra bundle size in because of new version of framework, or as my yarn logs nags about some packages having incorrect peer dependency to some older versions, the older dependencies gets bundled also?

[image: angular 8 loads application assets twice]

the content of index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{0}" dir="{1}" data-debug="{2}" data-user-id="{3}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
      name="viewport"
    />
    <link
      data-do-not-remove-me="true"
      href="/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.{1}.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      data-do-not-remove-me="true"
      href="/assets/styles/loader.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      data-do-not-remove-me="true"
      href="/assets/pwa/favicon.ico"
      rel="icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
    <title>Any Team | achasoft.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app-loading-container" class="waiting-container full-screen">
      <span class="waiting-spinner"></span>
    </div>
    <app-panel-root></app-panel-root>
    <script
      data-do-not-remove-me="true"
      type="text/javascript"
      src="/{0}/dynamics/translates"
    ></script>
    <script
      data-do-not-remove-me="true"
      type="text/javascript"
      src="/{0}/dynamics/enums"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

partial content of angular.json

```
{
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/main",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/main/src",
      "prefix": "app-main",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../backend/AchaApplication.Web/wwwroot/app/main",
            "index": "projects/main/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/main/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/main/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/main/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/main/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/main/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/main/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/main/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "main:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "main:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "main:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/main/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/main/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/main/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/main/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/main/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/main/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/main/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/main/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/main/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "projects/main/e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/main/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "main:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "main:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you specify the command used is it  `ng build --prod --aot` ?

Comment: Why have you disabled cache? I think that might have an ipact on the resources.

Comment: i am not using --aot
what is it?

Comment: only on development time, and when the console is open, only then the cache is disabled :)

Comment: @NavidKianfar `--aot` flag changes compiler  from `JIT` - Just in Time compiler to `AOT` - Ahead of time compiler . resulting in smaller optimised build  size  . ( recommended for production builds ) also there are additional  options like `--build-optimizer=true` and `--vendor-chunk=true` for more details   https://angular.io/cli/build

Answer (score 2):

This is because the new feature introduced in Angular 8 called **Differential Loading**.

**Differential loading is a strategy where the CLI builds two separate bundles as part of your deployed application.**

- The first bundle contains modern ES2015 syntax, takes advantage of
  built-in support in modern browsers, ships less polyfills, and
  results in a smaller bundle size.

  The second bundle contains code in the old ES5 syntax, along with all
  necessary polyfills. This results in a larger bundle size, but
  supports older browsers.

This strategy allows you to continue to build your web application to support multiple browsers, but only load the necessary code that the browser needs.

**[Configuring Differential Loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#configuring-differential-loading)**

Differential loading is supported by default with version 8 and later of the Angular CLI. For each application project in your workspace, you can configure how builds are produced based on the browserslist and tsconfig.json files in your application project.

Refer [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#configuring-differential-loading) for more details.

**Opting out of differential loading**

Differential loading can be explicitly disabled if it causes unexpected issues or you need to target ES5 specifically for legacy browser support.

To explicitly disable differential loading:

- Enable the dead or IE browsers in the `browserslist` config file by
  removing the `not` keyword in front of them. Set the target in the
  `compilerOptions` to `es5`.

This details is from the angular docs, refer [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) for more details

Answer (score 0):

It's because Angular has included these  js files in your index.html (of build) twice:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/runtime-es2015.de1f101ad38d40b1418d.js" type="module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/polyfills-es2015.e3505a8f9c19cc7a7967.js" type="module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/runtime-es5.d7d539b89689d64f8db9.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/polyfills-es5.91173d90822cf6a32960.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/main-es2015.bc80883a8d28e00c9ba5.js" type="module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/main-es5.55a8f5a8cbe64028a46a.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

And for size you should use `aot` compiler:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

Comment: no i did not, angular adds the assets to content of index.html file,

Comment: yes the build adds them, can you show angular.json config for build and please confirm which command you are using to `build` the project?

Comment: ng build --project panel --prod

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, just set "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json to prevent from differential loading, since the bundle sizes dont diffrent much, max 50K :)) why bother? and it saves a lot of time in build time :)